# selecting a single checkbox selects all the other checkboxes - flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. When I try to select a single card that in a ListView.builder, all the other cards that are in my list are selected.

I know that this is an issue of indexing. But, i am using the indexing to got through a list of data that i'm getting from the DB. So, the index in the itembuilder is int and not bool.

**My Code**

````
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  ServiceProvider serviceProvider = snapshot.data[index];
                  return new Card(
                    shape: selected
                        ? new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))
                        : new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
                    child: new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(serviceProvider.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, height: 1.5)),
                          new Text(serviceProvider.serviceType, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 1.5),),
                          new Text(serviceProvider.phoneNumber, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 1.5),),
                          new Text(serviceProvider.address, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 1.5),),
                          new Text(serviceProvider.location, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 1.5),),
                          new Text(serviceProvider.emailAddress, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 1.5),),
                          Container(
                            child: ButtonBar(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Checkbox(
                                    value: selected,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        selected = value;
                                        print(selected);
                                      });
                                      selectedName.add(serviceProvider.name);
                                      print(selectedName);
                                    }),
                                new RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text('Discard'),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      deleteMethod(serviceProvider.name);
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                new RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text('Verified'),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      updateMethod(serviceProvider.name);
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );```

How do i go about this?
````

Comment: I think the problem is with ` new Checkbox(
                                    value: selected` you are setting the same value for selected for all the children.

Comment: also, `selected = value;` when you already had `value: selected` is not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a [`Set`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Set-class.html) of the selected objects (in your case, `ServiceProvider`s, assuming their hashCode and equals are correctly overridden, which you can do in IntelliJ/Android Studio by `alt-insert`ing them). You can then see if the set contains an object (to figure out whether or not it's selected), remove an object (to remove selection), or add an object (to select).

To do this, keep the following at the top of your `State` class:

```
final selectedServiceProviders = Set<ServiceProvider>(); // creates an empty set (nothing selected by default)
```

Then, where you use `setState` to change the value of the `selected` boolean, simply use `setState` to modify the `selectedServiceProviders` with the corresponding method described in the first paragraph (`add()` or `remove()`). To check whether an object is selected, you can call `selectedServiceProviders.contains(object);`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get that well. Could you get me a little bit of detail on that please?
Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you think it is the proper answer, make sure to set it as the accepted answer.